# CAML query to retrieve list metadata

Tags: csom, caml-query

Does SharePoint expose a list that can be queried for list metadata as returned in List.Fields?

Background:
My aim is to request only the data that I need. When I write:

```
// string listName = "My List";
var myFields = context.LoadQuery(context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName).Fields);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

myFields contains 74 elements. However, I am interested in only a handful of these so I want to restrict myFields to that small subset. If I know the fields, I can add a `.Where(x => (x.Title == "Field1" || x.Title == "Field2" ...))`, but if I did not know the fields of interest, how would I limit the fields returned?

All my efforts to do it with pure CSOM code have failed. I have come to the conclusion that I need to construct a CAML query, but I am interested in the metadata (Title and InternalName) and not the contents of "My List". Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not possible to use CAML query to get/filter the list fields because of the `list.Fields` is a collection property, not a function which could accept the CAML query to filter out the fields.

Comment: OK, so I cannot query "My List", but is there a metadata list that I could query? For example, in an MS SQL Server database I can write: 

    `select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length
    from information_schema.columns
    where table_name = 'My List' and column_name in ('col1', 'col2', 'col3')`

Comment: @TestUser, no; it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have a List associated with a Content Type. So that you can have a set of Fields retrieved from the Content Type using CSOM.

please refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff630940(v=office.14).aspx) link to create a list using content type.

To create/edit a content type please refer [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-edit-content-types-3D5D45AF-608D-4183-8D51-073095FE0312).

Comment: Understood, but it is not my SharePoint site. I have to work with it as I find it.